# Rendering a loading state in a NextJS app

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-suspense

I am trying to render some stats on the landing page of the app I am working on and I want to use a skeleton as a placeholder for the numbers whilst they are fetched from the database.
This is the hierarchy:

```
<div>
{...}
    <Suspense fallback={<LoadComp/>}>
        {/*@ts-ignore*/}
        <SomeData/>
     </Suspense>
{...}
</div>
```

This is the SomeData component:

```
async function SomeData() {
    const data = await fetch("http://localhost:3000/api/test", {cache: "no-cache"}).then(res => res.json());
    return (
        <div>{data.message}</div>
    );
}
```

This is the LoadComp component:

```
function LoadComp() {
    console.log("loaded");
    return <div>Loading</div>
}
```

All of them are server components
The API endpoint is as follows:

```
export async function GET() {
    sleep(2); //sleeps for 2 seconds to create a delay.
    return NextResponse.json({message: "Hi"});
}
```

Now what is happening is that whilst `loaded` is printed in the console, the JSX of LoadComp is never actually rendered and the page will not be rendered until the request is completed. Another behavior I have noticed is that the fallback is only triggered on error. Say for example I cast the returning fetched data to some object, an error would be thrown but the Loading div would appear for a brief moment. Ignoring the fact that the fetch request is not cached, I would expect to see the Loading div but I'm not sure what I am doing wrong. Any help?